# Sencha touch chart not working after packaging the code

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-charts

I am trying to render sencha touch charts in an app,

following is the code of that view.

```
Ext.define('xxxx.view.dashboard.EventAnalyticsChart', {
extend : 'Ext.Panel',
xtype : 'analyticsChartPanel',
requires:['Ext.chart.grid.HorizontalGrid',
          'Ext.chart.grid.VerticalGrid'],
initialize : function() {

},
config : {

    layout:{
        type:'card'
    },
    items : [
             {
                // Toolbar to be displayed on the File Rack Screen
                xtype : 'toolbar',
                ui : 'light',
                docked : 'top',
                title : "Dashboard",

             }, 

             {
                xtype:'panel',
                docked : 'top',
                height:60,
                layout:{
                    type:'vbox',
                    align:'center',
                    pack:'center'
                },
                items:[



             {
                 xtype : 'chart',
                 background: 'white',
                 flipXY: true,
                 legend: {
                     position: "bottom"
                 },
                 store: {
                        fields: ['name', 'g1', 'g2', 'g3'],
                        data: [
                            {"name": "Work", "g1": 2.67, "g2": 14.87, "g3": 0.41},
                            {"name": "Office", "g1": 1.90, "g2": 5.72, "g3": 14.80},
                            {"name": "Google", "g1": 18.34, "g2": 0.04, "g3": 22.35},
                            {"name": "Facebook", "g1": 21.37, "g2": 2.13, "g3": 12.98},

                        ]
                    },

                    interactions: ['panzoom'],

                    //set legend configuration
                    legend: {
                        position: 'right',
                        width: 80
                    },

                    //define the x and y-axis configuration.
                    axes: [
                        {
                            type: 'numeric',
                            position: 'bottom',
                            grid: true,
                            minimum: 0
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'category',
                            position: 'left'
                        }
                    ],

                    series: [
                             {
                                 type: 'bar',
                                 xField: 'name',
                                 yField: ['g1', 'g2', 'g3'],
                                 axis: 'bottom',
                                 highlight: true,
                                 showInLegend: true,
                                 style: {
                                     stroke: 'rgb(40,40,40)',
                                     maxBarWidth: 30
                                 },
                                 // Cycles the red, green, and blue fill mode over the 2008, 2009,.., 2011, 2012 items
                                 // subStyle parameters also override style parameters
                                 subStyle: {
                                     fill: ["#115fa6", "#94ae0a", "#a61120", "#ff8809", "#ffd13e", "#a61187", "#24ad9a", "#7c7474", "#a66111"]
                                 }
                             }
                         ]


             }


    ],


}
```

});

After building the sencha code, when the packaged code is run i get the below error.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined app.js:1

i think i am not loading some of the classes needed for the charts. Please do guide me with this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Working fine after including following classes.

```
          'Ext.chart.axis.Numeric',
          'Ext.chart.axis.Category',
          'Ext.chart.series.Line',
          'Ext.chart.interactions.PanZoom',
          'Ext.chart.series.Bar'
```